# Link 2 Related Collections together

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter through 2 collections which are two child collections brought back from a parent collection.

```
$producers = Producer::with( [
        'intakes' => function ( $query ) use ( $dates ) {
            $query->whereIn( 'collection_date', $dates )->orderBy('collection_date', 'asc')->get();
        }
    ], [
        'nmls' => function ( $query ) use ( $dates ) {
            $query->whereIn( 'sample_date', $dates )->orderBy('sample_date', 'asc')->get();
        }
    ] )->get()->find(1);
```

The collection of producers that I get back isn't ordered by the date so I'm trying to do the following in the blade file:

```
@foreach ($pro->intakes as $intake)
        @foreach ($pro->nmls as $nml)
            @if($intake->collection_date === $nml->sample_date)
                @include('milk.row', compact('pro', 'intake', 'nml'))
                @break
            @else
                @include('milk.row', compact('pro', 'intake', 'nml'))
                @break
            @endif
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But it doesn't work and I either get the NML data without Intakes, or I get Intakes with duplicated NML and vice versa.

I don't know if there's a way to link two children collections together to extract one master one which then belongs to a producer?

e.g

```
          * Producer
   nml  /   \ intake
        join
        \   /
          * Sample
```

I'm totally lost, I had an approach where I'd find the max() in NML and Intake, take the largest number then loop through the children, but it doesn't work with larger chunks of data as I thought it would.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

@edit

This is how I retrive the data on blade file:

```
<tr action="{{route('milk.data.updateData')}}" class="updateData">
<th scope="row"><a href="{{route('producer.show', $pro->id)}}"
                   data-tooltip="View producer">{{$pro->producer_number}} <i
                class="fas fa-link"></i></a></th>
<td>{{$pro->producer_business_name}}</td>
@if(!empty($nml->sample_date))
    N <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($nml->sample_date)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
@else
    I <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($intake->collection_date)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
@endif
<input type="hidden" name="nid" value="{{!empty($nml->id) ? $nml->id : '' }}">
<input type="hidden" name="iid" value="{{!empty($intake->id) ? $intake->id :''}}">
...
...
...
...
</tr>
```

Comment: you can give more information to clarify, says how do you want to present the data in view?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks.
Essentially, I need to link both relations (nml + intake) using the sample/collection date to be displayed in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically group by **nmls** and **intakes** data by date, and loop through all the date to see if there are any **nmls** and **intakes** exist.

There are a lot [helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) can help, such as `keyBy`:

```
// following relations is group by date
// eg: [ 'date' => [ { intake }, { intake } ... ], ... ]
$intakes = $pro->intakes->keyBy('collection_date');
$nmls = $pro->nmls->keyBy('sample_date');

// get list of dates and sorted
$intake_dates = $intakes->keys();
$nml_dates = $nmls->keys();
$dates = $intake_dates->merge($nml_dates)->unique()->sort()->values();

// then you can loop through all the date
// and transform the data in controller and present in the view
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if (isset($intakes[$date])) {
        ...
    }
    if (isset($nmls[$date])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ben for your input. In the end this is how I tackled it.

So, essentially I loop through copies of each Collection and if the date from 1 collection matches the 2 date and the foreign key is the same in both collections I then push the object to the brand new collection where 2 previous collections are merged. After that I remove both items from both collections.

It might not be the best approach, but using **Bens** approach returned hell of a lot of duplicates (something I was trying to avoid) however, his answer was really valuable to me.

Best Regards.

```
$milk_data = collect();

foreach($dup_intake as $keyI => $intake) {
        foreach($dup_nmls as $keyN => $nml) {
            if($intake->collection_date == $nml->sample_date && $intake->producer_id == $nml->producer_id) {
                $na = $nml->toArray();
                $ia = $intake->toArray();
                $collection = array_merge($na, $ia);
                $milk_data->push($collection);
                $dup_nmls->forget($keyN);
                $dup_intake->forget($keyI);
            } else if($milk_data->contains($nml) || !$milk_data->contains($intake) && $intake->producer_id == $nml->producer_id) {
                $milk_data->push($intake->toArray());
            } else if($milk_data->contains($intake) || !$milk_data->contains($nml) && $intake->producer_id == $nml->producer_id ) {
                $milk_data->push($nml->toArray());
            }
        }
    }
```